# Adding space between subfigures of tikzpicture (for caption)

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subfloats

I'm trying to draw two figures next to each others using **tikzpicture**. It's working fine, but the **caption** of the sub-figures is looking weird.

I tried adding the \qquad's, but I'm still having the same problem.

Here's my code;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!hb]%
\centering
\subfigure[Caption for subfigure 1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
\node{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\subfigure[Caption for subfigure 2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
\node{}
        child{node{}}
        child[missing];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here's the resulting image

[image]

Comment: It's a bounding box problem. Add `\path (0,0) rectangle(3,3);` to both tikzpictures to see the effect. So either adjust the bounding boxes within `tikzpicture` environments or use minipages or other artificial boxes.

Comment: @percusse: Using `\path (0,0) rectangle(3,3);` solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Note that the subfigures are not centered with respect to the subcaptions. Because the quick fix starts from the origin and the nodes are also aligned towards the origin too. So give explicit coordinates to your nodes to avoid that.

Comment: The centering can be obtained by `\path (-2,0) rectangle (2,0);` which also doesn't add to the picture's height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bounding box problem.
you can add a node with [minimum width=xxxcm]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!hb]%
\centering
\subfigure[Caption for subfigure 1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
\node(a){5};
\end{scope}
\node[minimum width=3.5cm] at (a){};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\subfigure[Caption for subfigure 2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
\node(a){}
        child{node{}}
        child[missing];

\end{scope}
  \node[minimum width=3.5cm] at (a){};      
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: node]